# Gmail account won't complete loading on iMac - now closed as it magically worked today

Tags: gmail, mac

I have 2 Gmail accounts. My usual one stopped loading at 90% on the blue loading line.  It will work if I use the HTML for slow connections but if I try to go to standard view it sticks at 90% again. The other Gmail account worked fine until today when it also stopped at the 90% loading mark and doesn't load any further.  What can I do to fix this?

I have OSX 10.9.5, Safari 9.1.3, I have checked for any updates. No Gmail add-ons or browser extensions. I have cleared caches and all history, browser and cookies. I also deleted a big chunk of emails and my usage is less than 50% of my total space allowance on Gmail.

This only happens on my iMac; Gmail works fine on my laptop.

Comment: Are you using Gmail or Inbox by Gmail? Have you tried with Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: using gmail.  No not tried Chrome or Firefox.   its weird that it loads fine with the other gmail account.

Comment: Try using Chrome and share with us what happened.

Comment: I see a lot of people having problems with Chrome on their macs.  Prefer not to go there - unless there is no other way - which seems mad as my alternative google account works just fine.

Comment: then try on Firefox or any other modern browser.

Comment: Or add more details, like the OS and browser versions if you have installed Gmail addons, browser extensions, etc.

Comment: I have OSX 10.9.5, Safari 9.1.3, I have checked for any updates. No gmail add ons or browser extensions.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the details about your issue. Comments are intended to be temporary.

Comment: By the other hand, as you are using old OS and browser versions, this issue is very likely to be related to not having enough resources. I suggest you to ask on [apple.se].

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a transient bug, since fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made no other changes other than in my question but magically today the issue of gmail not loading past 90% is fixed and it works on both my accounts.   So this question is now closed.  Thanks to all who commented.